# Can't write on file with python flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write on a file with flask, with some information that I receive on a website. However, it gives me the 500 error on the specific line when I'm trying to open a file to be writable.
I've tried opening it from a variety of ways like this:

```py
with open('scooters.csv','w') as csv_file:
```

and like this:

```py
csv_file = open('scooters.csv','w')
```

And both of these give the 500 error

I can open it with:

```py
csv_file = open('scooters.csv')
```

But then, when I want to write with:

```py
csv_file.writerow(row)
```

It gives me the 500 error again

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Where are you running your Flask app? If it's an external hosting service, they simply may not allow to write to files

Comment: Take a look at the command-line output of your flask app. It should clarify what type of error is occurring. As @ForceBru suggested, I'm thinking that you're running into a permission issue in whatever folder you're running your application. You may need to specify a specific writeable path (assuming you even have one with your web host).

Comment: Do not add "Fixed" to your title and the answer into your post. If you believe the answer to your question could be useful to others, then *post it as an answer*.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *user* running the python process.

I see relative pathnames.
Are you sure that *user* can write to the full pathname?